# Sensor for very low temperature (liquid nitrogen)

Tags: sensor, temperature

I'm looking for a way to measure temperatures in range of 40 to -200 °C (100 to −320 °F). The usual DS18B20 digital thermometer works only down to -55 °C (-67 °F).

A precision of 2 °C would be good enough.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I want to give this hint (as I used many of those sensors myself) http://www.lakeshore.com/Products/Cryogenic-Temperature-Sensors/Pages/default.aspx (I hope it does not come off as advertisement, I am not affiliated with Lakeshore). Thing is, those are *dumb* sensors, you'll have to build a control circuit yourself (e.g. a precision current source and precision voltmeter) - which could be part of good answers.

Comment: related but not a dupe: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/87905/sensor-for-ultralow-to-85c-freezer-monitor/87959#87959

Comment: Please clarify if you are searching for a general technology or a specific product.

Comment: @ Ghanima : the link inside of the post you linked to the https://www.adafruit.com/products/269 will probably work form. Thnx!

Answer (score 4):

Answer is simple: **thermocouple**.

Thermocouple type K (chromel - alumel) works from -200°C and has very linear characteristics. It's very popular and cheap, many multimeters use it as a temperature sensor. Type T will be better for such low temperatures, but it is hard to buy and not as cheap as K.

Another solution is a platinum resistive sensor, like Pt100, but it is not as linear as thermocouple.

Comment: Where did you found that Pt100 has unpleasant characteristics below 0C ?  http://www.ni.com/tutorial/7115/en/

Comment: @MarkoBuršič My mistake, I've looked at wrong graph in some Pt100 datasheet. I've just edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A commonly-used cheap sensor for LN2 is a standard silicon diode. Measure the forward drop at a constant current.